# WordPress plugin - separate forms - one plugin page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, settings

Is it possible to have two forms for saving plugin options (one plugin page), and to submit each form separately?

Using one form is really easy.
For example, plugin page (in dashboard) can contain this (minimum):

```
<form action="options.php" method="post" >
    <?php settings_fields( 'my-settings' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'my-settings' ); ?>

    //more input fields

    <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
```

And for saving options this will work just fine. But, is it possible to have two forms like this, using the same plugin options page (but on submit, to save only options from form, which submit button I click)?

Currently, if I create another form, and hit submit, it will still submit both of these forms, not just one (for which I clicked submit button).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking this approach, I would do this using ajax instead. It's easier to implement and will give your plugin a very web 2.0 feel. In your case, its actually easier to implement the ajax approach rather then try to do what you are doing. [Here is](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) something to get you started.

```
<?php
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'my_action_javascript');

function my_action_javascript() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        whatever: 1234
    };

    // since 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

Then you can handle the request like this:

```
<?php 

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

Comment: yes. At the end i had to do it with ajax. It requires a little bit more work (security need to be implemented manualy), but worked just fine!